# To find 256 point FFT in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am implementing FFT in Libero using an 'FFT IPcore'. I have got an output,but I want to verify its correctness. I have the input values with me and I want to find the FFT coefficients of these values using MAT LAB .

Comment: can i just give those 256 values as a vector and find FFT using 'fft(x,n)' function

Comment: can you give your current code to call the function and the size (dimensions) of your result?

Comment: heads up if you're using a fixed point implementation. your scaling may vary